# Not being prompted to Migrate from SharePoint 2010 to 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, upgrade

I'm currently working on a project to migrate a SharePoint 2010 project to 2013 then eventually to 2016.  I've found several sites that have told me all I need to do is load project solution on visual studio 2012/2013 and I will be prompted to migrate solution to 2013. I'm not getting this prompted at all.

Is their away to for migration to occur via cmd line?

I used agent ransack and I'm unable to find any reference to TargetOfficeVersion in any of my .csproj files.  Of note:
1) this solution contains 4 separate SharePoint projects that all need to be migrated.
2) When I was onboard they were already using vs2015 to handle fixes and code pushes.

Any help/guidance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

By any chance, is it possible that it is already converted before you were on board. Check the DLL versions of SharePoint...is it referring to

You can do it manually with below instruction.

If you are deploying sharepoint 2010 wsp in SP2013, the files will get deployed to 14 hive instead of 15 hive and the target framework would still refer to 3.5 instead of 4.5. so you need to make the below 2 changes

1. Set the SharePointProductVersion to 15.0 instead of 14.0 in the manifest file for the Solution element
2. Set the .net Framework target to 4.5 by changing the TargetOfficeVersion for the project files

You can check the below posts on hot to do these things

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointdevpreview/thread/93bc1f0a-b84a-41df-9c13-2bdfa92a529f

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/522220/ConvertingplusmultipleplusSharePointplus2010pluspr

hope this helps

Answer taken from Reference - https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/f60ecfa6-485f-4f55-aea3-7568fe680dc4/how-to-upgrade-a-sp-2010-solution-to-2013-and-continue-development-with-the-new-object-model?forum=sharepointadmin